# Maven Deploy Plugin S3 Wagon with Java 11 not working with JAXB

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, jaxb, java-11

I am trying to migrate my builds from Java 8 to Java 11. My repository is located in an S3 bucket. To make S3 wagon working with Java-11 I've added JAXB as a dependency of a plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't help and deploy plugin fails.

Error log fragment (you can see jaxb in the classpath):

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy-file: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/3.0.0-M1/maven-deploy-plugin-3.0.0-M1.jar
urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar
urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar
urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar
urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.8/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar
urls[6] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.8.1/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.16/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar
urls[8] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
urls[9] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
urls[10] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
urls[11] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
urls[12] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
urls[13] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
urls[14] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[15] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.10.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.10.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
urls[17] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.1.0/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
urls[18] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
urls[19] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
urls[20] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
```

Anything more missing in the setup?

-edit-

As a solution, I've managed to make it working by moving wagon extension:

```
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.zalando.org.springframework.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.RELEASE-zal-2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>
```

Into `maven-deploy-plugin` dependencies section. But to me it looks like a workaround rather than an answer to the problem.

- edit 2 -

The final solution that works for us is to use S3 wagon extension that is built with newer AWS SDK (picked `com.github.nodely:maven-s3-wagon:1.0.0`). Works as desired (adding extension as dependency to plugins was torublesome because it had to be added to any plugin utilizing S3 repository).

Still would be nice to understand original issue and how to apply dependencies to such runtime cases.

Comment: JAXB has been removed with JDK10 or JDK11 I'm not 100% sure at the moment...but based on the error message you are manually doing `mvn deploy:deploy-file` which is usually a bad idea...

Comment: Neither of the information helps. I know it was removed, that's why the solution is to add jaxb to the plugin dependency. The problem is that it doesn't work when S3 wagon is defined as extension. And I use `deploy:deploy-file` because that's what I need to do, it's exactly what I need to deploy external file into internal repo during the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the exactly same issue but with a different implementation of wagon with this extension. It must be version 1.2.0 that support Java 11.

```
<extension>
    <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</extension>
```